# MySQL Stored Procedure that compares each row's date field and updates based on curdate()

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

This might be a noob question, but I tried googling about this issue and I haven't found any solution for it (I think). Anyway, I need to compare a date in a row from a mysql table to the current date and update the row depending on the results. I made a stored procedure that will be called by an event every x minutes. Here is my code for the sp:

```
delimiter //
        CREATE PROCEDURE checkPromoValidity()
        BEGIN
         DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
         DECLARE id INT;
         DECLARE lvn_status INT;
         DECLARE lvn_validUntil DATE;
         DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT promos.PROMO_NUMBER,promos.VALID_UNTIL,promos.status FROM MDCH_NEW.promos;
         DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

        open cur1;
        check_loop: LOOP
        fetch cur1 into id,lvn_validUntil,lvn_status;
        IF done THEN
              LEAVE check_loop;
            END IF;

        IF (lvn_validUntil > CURDATE()) THEN 
            update mdch_new.promos set MDCH_NEW.PROMOS.status = 0 where mdch_new.promos.PROMO_NUMBER = id;
        END IF;
        end LOOP;
        close cur1;       
        END //

MDCH_NEW = database name
PROMOS= table name
```

EDIT: I CHANGED my delimiter to // just to see
edit2: added space after the final word, still getting the error below.. :(

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 23

Comment: Where is your delimiter?

Comment: oops i forgot about that. now i made it like the answer below, and i'm now getting this error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 22

Comment: If that is your syntax above you need to add a space between the final word and the delimiter - `END //`

Comment: It won't work.. I keep getting this error.. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 22

Comment: u doing cross db action here i take it

Comment: what cross db action?

Comment: u are in db XXXX (maybe), and you are doing cross-db updates to MDCH_NEW, mdch_new, and where you are not referencing db name, you are either in XXXX <> mdch_new or there anyway, ... who is to know (but you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delimiter $$
create procedure return7 ()
BEGIN
  select 7;
END
$$
```

call return7();

you are free to re-use this code

Comment: If you're going to demonstrate, please get the syntax correct.

Comment: I made it END$$ and now I'm getting this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 22

Comment: if it's not the delimiter, then Jay and I are off, fix the innards.

Comment: marked as answer. I just removed the line delimiter $$ because i forgot that i had written // in the delimiter textbox... Sry for the trouble.